# Moving From FreeNAS to Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, zfs

So I've just bought and installed an HP Proliant Microserver gen8 and upgraded it to 10GB RAM.
I've installed FreeNAS onto a USB key (16GB) as recommended and FreeNAS is working well. Unfortunately, I didn't understand the limitations of FreeNAS at the time and I'm finding that it isn't for me and my situation.

To that end, what I'd like to do is install Ubuntu server onto the microserver and reuse the existing ZFS pools, rather than having to copy all of the data back off the drives as I've already been busy moving data for a good while now.

I have 4x3Tb drives split into 2 pools, each with a 3Tb mirror. I do have an SSD on order, so I'll be using that to store the OS.
Can I reuse the drives as-is or am I facing the headache of wiping them and setting them up again?
Any suggestions or info much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm planning to do the same with the next ubuntu server LTS release, since it integrates zfs officially.

Answer (score 0):

- install zfs tools on ubuntu

```bsh
PS> sudo apt install zfsutils-linux
```

- view available zpools

```bsh
PS> zpool import
   pool: zpool
     id: 4668569581804914545
  state: ONLINE
 status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool.
 action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier, though
        some features will not be available without an explicit 'zpool upgrade'.
 config:

        zpool       ONLINE
          raidz1-0  ONLINE
            sde     ONLINE
            sdc     ONLINE
            sdd     ONLINE
            sdf     ONLINE
```

- import the zpool

```bsh
PS> sudo zpool import zpool -f
PS> zpool status
  pool: zpool
 state: ONLINE
status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool. The pool can
        still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
        the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
        the features. See zpool-features(5) for details.
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 30h35m with 0 errors on Mon Jul 15 06:35:09 2019
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        zpool       ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            sde     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
            sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0
```